# Why is the accuracy of multi-labels classification using the sigmoid" activation function is much more than using "softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, nlp

I do multi-label text classification using Bi-LSTM classifier, that means there are instances in the dataset of 11 classes that have more than 1 label. When I use the "sigmoid" activation function with "binary_crossentropy" loss function, I get higher accuracy than using "softmax" activation function with "categorical_crossentropy" loss function. why?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing **multi-label classification**.

Softmax function forces the output probabilities to have a sum equals to 1. So you can't have a final output like `[0, 1, 0, 1]` (which you would like for a multi-label classification). Sigmoid does not have such constraint. *Softmax is not suited for multi-label classification.*

It probably is the reason of your results.

You should dig further into cross-entropy loss:
[Cross-entropy for classification](https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-entropy-for-classification-d98e7f974451)
[Should I use a categorical cross-entropy or binary cross-entropy loss for binary predictions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260505/should-i-use-a-categorical-cross-entropy-or-binary-cross-entropy-loss-for-binary)

Comment: Many thanks, etiennedm